# jQuery deferred objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, deferred

I'm having a tough time wrapping my head around deferred objects in jQuery.

E.G,

I thought I could use the following syntax, but this is actually running both success and fail when a success happens. I thought fail would only run if the ajax call fails?

```
checkFoo(widget)
.success(step1, step2)
.fail(alert("failed"));
```

checkFoo is an AJAX call like so

```
function checkFoo(widget){
   return $.ajax({
          url: "foo.php",
          data: widget,
          format: json
   });
}
```

Comment: The success method is deprecated in jQuery 1.8. You should use done instead of success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code

```
checkFoo(widget)
.success( step1(), step2() )
.fail( alert("checkfoo failed") );
```

**calls** `step1` and `step2` and `alert` *immediately*, and passes their return values into the `success` or `fail` methods. Exactly like

```
foo(bar());
```

...calls `bar` and passes its return value into `foo`.

If you want to tell jQuery to call `step1` and `step2` on success, and do the `alert` on failure, you pass in function references:

```
checkFoo(widget)
.success( step1, step2 )      // <== No parens, `step1` refers to a *function*
.fail( function() {           // <== Wrap a function around the alert
    alert("checkfoo failed");
});
```

Comment: Thanks T.J, this is what I ended up doing. I also went ahead and changed success to done.

Answer (score 4):

This here is bad:

```
.success( step1(), step2() )
```

That will pass the result of executing `step1()` and the `step2()` as arguments.

But this here is good!

```
.success( step1, step2 )
```

It will pass the functions themselves in to be executed later.

Comment: Thanks for that tip Alex. Any idea on why fail is running even though my ajax call is successful in my above example?

Comment: You might want to use `.then(success, failure)` or use `.fail(failure).success(success)` as, I think, `.success(func1, func2)` just indicates two things to run when it resolves.

Comment: @JasonWells because of the _exact_ same problem. You are calling `alert()` and then providing the result as the callback. You need to pass in a function.

Comment: Good point @AlexWayne so the alert() needs wrapping in a `function() {alert(...)}`

Answer (score 2):

You are using them the wrong way..

The `.success()` and `.fail()` take callback function as parameters..

so try

```
checkFoo(widget)
.success( function(){
    step1(); 
    step2();
})
.fail( function(){
    alert("checkfoo failed");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to pass a fhnction expression into `fail`:

```
.fail(function() {

});
```